# C++ Subclass method overriding

Tags: c++, class, overriding

I feel like total dumb on this one. I want to create a subclass of my class Model:

```
class Model {
public:
    Model(const GLchar* path, const GLuint& amountLoaded);
protected:
    void loadModel();
};
```

It should look like this:

```
class AnimatedModel : public Model {
public:
    AnimatedModel(const GLchar * path, const GLuint & amountLoaded);
protected:
    /*Override!*/
    void loadModel();
};
```

Then, form the outside, I want to create a new `AnimatedModel`. The AnimatedModel contructor simply passes its arguments to the Model constructor. The `Model` constructor then calls the Method `loadModel()`. I hoped, that this call would then reach my overridden version of this method, but it doesn't seem to work like this... What am i missing here?

Comment: Also read this: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#calling-virtuals-from-ctors

Comment: @Erik, you need set: `virtual void loadModel();` on Model class

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Oh yes, you're right. I didn't know about that. thanks for clarification

Comment: A quick and easy way to spot this problem in a larger codebase, btw, is to use the `override` keyword in the derived class function signature - if the signature of the base class method you're overriding doesn't match (or if it's not `virtual` in the base) then the compiler will give you a clear error.